# How to convert string range into the float or int dtype of average?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data as such:

```
datetime      range 
2022-10-10    50-54
2022-10-12    30-36
```

range is object dtype. How can I get to:

```
datetime      range   mean 
2022-10-10    50-54    52.0
2022-10-12    30-36    33.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) your string on `-`, then convert to integer and get the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) per row:

```
df['mean'] = df['range'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int).mean(axis=1)
```

Or use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np
df['mean'] = np.loadtxt(df['range'], delimiter='-').mean(axis=1)
```

output:

```
     datetime  range  mean
0  2022-10-10  50-54  52.0
1  2022-10-12  30-36  33.0
```